# C# JSON.net DeserializeObject<Class> fills up a with null

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Having some problems deserializing JSON in JSON.net.

First of all I am pulling JSON from my source that looks like the following.

```
{
"guest": {
    "id": 11111,        
    "A": "bla",
    "B": "bla",
    "C": false,
    "credentials": [
        {
            "id": 222,
            "Z": "bla",
            "accounts": [
                {
                    "id": 01,
                    "type": "bla"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 222,
            "Z": "bla",
            "accounts": [
                {
                    "id": 02,
                    "type": "bla"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 333,
            "Z": "bla",
            "accounts": [
                {
                    "id": 03,
                    "type": "bla"
                },
                {
                    "id": 04,
                    "type": "bla"
                },
                {
                    "id": 05,
                    "type": "bla"
                },
            ]
        },          
    ]
}
```

}

Within my code I have the following classes

```
  public class guest
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string A { get; set; }

    public string B { get; set; }

    public bool C { get; set; }

    public IList<credentials> credentials { get; set; }

}

  public class credentials
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Z { get; set; }

    public IList<accounts> accounts { get; set; }
}


 public class accounts
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

From this point I get my JSON from an HttpWebResponse and deserialize.

```
var httpResponseGetResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequestGetResponse.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponseGetResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var result =  streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            guest deseriazedJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<guest>(result);
        }
```

This ends with everything being NULL. Am I blind and missing something in the JSON.net docs?

Appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try to look at hundreds of existing questions on this site and use online converters to generate a proper structure? At least fix you json and add missing commas

Comment: "Z": "bla" also has a missing comma

Comment: Apologies I edited the JSON down as its actually about 70 variables per type.

Comment: Are you sure that "response" actually contains the JSON String?

Comment: ABPerson - I can see the response come as output this to Console to check that everything seems all and well. Like the person below said I also tried adding a blank property to get into this before I asked anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an object with a single property named `guest` on a root level of your `JSON`. So it can be deserialized in next scenario:

```
public class Response 
{
    public guest guest { get; set; }
}

...

var httpResponseGetResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequestGetResponse.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponseGetResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var result =  streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var deseriazedJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);
}
```

It's better to change your JSON input to avoid an extra wrapper:

```
{
    "id": 11111,        
    "A": "bla",
    "B": "bla",
    "C": false,
    "credentials": [
        {
            "id": 222,
            "Z": "bla"
            "accounts": [
                {
                    "id": 01,
                    "type": "bla"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 222,
            "Z": "bla"
            "accounts": [
                {
                    "id": 02,
                    "type": "bla"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 333,
            "Z": "bla"
            "accounts": [
                {
                    "id": 03,
                    "type": "bla"
                },
                {
                    "id": 04,
                    "type": "bla"
                },
                {
                    "id": 05,
                    "type": "bla"
                },
            ]
        },          
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I actually attempted this before I asked anything on here and still ended up with "Null" in everything. I also cant edit the JSON as its being pulled from a 3rd party. That little snippet is a TINY amount of the huge amount of data being pulled.

Comment: @Zaffro well I'm trying to reproduce your example with the structure from the question and received successfully deserialized object. https://habrastorage.org/webt/z7/r2/1e/z7r21efmdmsfrbsdhypzroefaso.png

Comment: Ctrl-Z through all the changes I made and you are 100% correct. I did create the class but in my frustration never updated JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result) and left it pointing to guest. In short i'm an idiot. Thanks very much for your time!